# How to implement both SSR and CSR in a single React project

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, server-side, client-side

I am trying to create a react-server side boilerplate using express. How can I configure it so that some pages get generated on the server and send raw HTML to the browser and for some pages, I don't want any SEO and other stuff so just want to send compile javascript code to the browser where browser compiles it and create needed HTML and make API calls.
Is this kind of configuration possible? Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: You could configure certain routes in your server to use `react-dom/server` and server render the pages and configure other routes to send a single HTML file with the `<script />` attached so that those are rendered on the client side

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to do this